# AJAX call with jQuery and get result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?page=Chat",
    data: { action: "sendMessage" },
}).done(function(msg) {
    jQuery("#main").append(msg);
});
```

and my PHP code simple returns a string

```
return 'myString';
```

Unfortunately `myString` is not added to the `#main-container`. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Try echoing the string, and add a `fail()` function to your `$.ajax` to catch errors!

Comment: Do you have any errors on the page? If you open your browser's developer tools do you see the request being sent?

Comment: I don't know but sometimes IE works strange if you put one extra comma in the object. Possibly it makes sense. Otherwise, the code looks fine.

Comment: You're going to have to do some basic debugging.  Does the AJAX call happen?  What response comes back from the server?  Does the call-back function get executed?

Comment: response is 200 OK, but echoing already solved the problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `return` only works inside PHP, to get something back to the ajax call it needs to be "displayed", or in other words use `echo` or `print`. Cleanest would probably be `exit('myString')`.

Answer (score 0):

The OP tried to treat php pages as functions but php pages cannot return value like functions.
Therefore the solution of this question is to print $mystring in php page instead of returning it.